# XAMPP localhost redirects to localhost/dashboard

Tags: xampp

I've just installed xampp-win32-5.5.30 and in xampp control panel both Apache and mysql started without any error but I found:

1)***localhost*** in my browser redirects to another page ***localhost/dashboard/*** and not the xampp start page.

2)***localhost/xampp*** shows the following:

```
Index of /xampp

[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[PARENTDIR] Parent Directory        -    
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.5.30 Server at localhost Port 80
```

In ***C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php*** file:

```
<?php   
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) 
    {
            $uri = 'https://';
    } 
    else 
    {
            $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
    exit;
?>

Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(
```

Is there something wrong with the installation?

Answer (score 8):

Delete that file(index.php), you will get the list of directories and files from htdocs folder.

Comment: For people visiting in the future, follow this to get 'index of' page when hitting localhost

Answer (score 4):

In the file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf change this:

```
# Virtual hosts
# Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

with this:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then, In the file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf add with something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sbyc.byc.local
    ServerAlias sbyc.byc.local
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/byc-mineduc01-ges/app"
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/byc-mineduc01-ges/app">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/sbyc.byc.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem and after some experiments I found decision. The problem was in .htaccess file, which located in root folder of my site folder. Content of .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

When I remove slash before index.php in last row:

```
RewriteRule . index.php
```

My site home page opened normally.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
```

Performs redirect to localhost/dashboard/

Everything works as expected, if you clear this file and put some text, like "Hello world", you should see it on http://localhost/

Comment: Yes, that is true, but how can I get to the XAMPP start page where I can set password for MYSQL database. Typing http://localhost/security/xamppsecurity.php gives an Object not found Error 404...

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that your `.htaccess` file is properly configured? This is what solved the problem for me. `RewriteEngine` is ON and your `RewriteBase` should be specified, so if your website directory is within the `htdocs` folder your `RewriteBase` should be `/MyWebsite/`.

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same problem.

Always when I try to access the file created in the htdocs, it was getting redirected to localhost/dashboard.

What I did was, I checked all the files present in htdocs.
There was a file applications. I opened it and found that it was actually redirecting me to the dashboard.

So, I moved that file from htdocs.

I could access my files from htdocs now without any redirection issues.

Answer (score -1):

As usually problem:

- `wp_config.php` at your local file
  -`wp_option` after your importing your database
- `vhost.txt` at `xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
         DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/apps/magento/htdocs"
         ServerName sitename.local
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by removing the file named index in htdocs. Since that was redirecting me to the dashboard.