# chrome directing to "http://localhost/dashboard/"

Tags: xampp

I just installed XAMPP for windows 7,I started MySql and Apache, the problem I have is, when I type localhost in my browser "Google Chrome" it sends me to "http://localhost/dashboard/"

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAMPP localhost redirects to localhost/dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284095/xampp-localhost-redirects-to-localhost-dashboard)

Answer (score 0):

delete the "index"(xampp/htdocs)