# I need help removing the root folder from my website URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I just launched a website using XAMPP, and I got everything working for the most part. However, when I type my url "www.mysite.com" , it launches the website but with the url "www.mysite.com/website". "Website" being the name of the folder my files are in. How do I get rid of the "/website" from my address bar?

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ user-profile.php?user_username=$1 [NC,L]
```

index.php file in htdocs folder in XAMPP folder

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/website/');
    exit;
?>
```

You can probably tell I'm very new to this, but I've looked everywhere and I can't figure out how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, perhaps change the DocumentRoot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284095/xampp-localhost-redirects-to-localhost-dashboard

Comment: Your index.php adds a "Location" header. This issues a redirect. Can you can remove the line "header('Location: '.$uri.'/website/');" and see if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

Your index is pointing to the website directory.

Change

```
header('Location: '.$uri.'/website/');
```

to just

```
header('Location: '.$uri);
```

Better yet check for and adjust for httpS in .htaccess directly so you don't have to rely on index.php to adjust the protocol being used.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you handled by PHP. This is a web server job. just create VirtualHost in apache with ServerName [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) and add your DocumentRoot /path_to_htdocs/website. Somthing like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/path_to_htdocs/website"
        ServerName www.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
<Directory "/path_to_htdocs/website">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think if virtual host is what you wanted but I hope this [link](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/302/how-to-setup-a-virtual-host-locally-with-xampp-in-ubuntu) help. Cheers